# Config file is messed up after specifying GPG as program

Tags: git

I'm trying to sign my commits with a GPG key but I ended up messing something up in my config with by executing this line.

```
git config gpg.program = /usr/local/bin/gpg
```

Now I can't use git because I get the following errors:

```
error: cannot run =: No such file or directory
error: could not run gpg.
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Can anyone help fix it? I looked in my global .gitconfig but I don't see anything weird in it.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax of `git config` is without the "`=`".
Actually you set your gpg.program to *=* as you can see from the output of the following command:

```
git config gpg.program
```

You should execute this line to set the correct gpg.program

```
git config gpg.program /usr/local/bin/gpg
```

Comment: Yes, I fixed the issue by going into my repo  and executing "open .git/config". I then found out a syntax error in it and removed the line to fix the issue.